# Why are the products of Grignard reaction on an alpha-chiral ketone diastereomers rather than a racemate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, grignard-reagent

> Comment on stereochemistry of products.
>
> [image: (4S)-4-methylhexan-3-one to (4S)-3,4-dimethylhexan-3-ol in the presence of methylmagnesium bromide and ammonium chloride]

This is a [Grignard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reaction) and the product has two chiral carbons. I think it should be a *[racemic mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racemic_mixture)*.

However, my teacher says the correct answer is *diastereomers*. He says if the reactant has no chiral carbon and product is chiral, then it would be a racemic mixture. But why?

Comment: If a reaction scrambles an existing single stereo-center, you get a racemic mixture. If it creates a new stereo-center without affecting the existing one, and the reactant was chiral (not a racemic mixture), you can't get a pair of mirror images. The new stereo-center will be a mix of R and S, and the existing one will be just R or just S, so it is a mixture of diastereomers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reaction introduces a new chiral center into your mix, that chiral carbon being the one that has the tertiary alcohol on it (let’s call this #2).

The product will produce a mixture of those chiral centers being flipped between *R* and *S*, but you need to remember that there is a preexisting chiral center (let’s call it #1) that we have before creating this new one.

Recall:

- enantiomers occur when *all* chiral centers are flipped
- diastereomers occur when one, but *not all*, chiral centers are flipped.

This reaction can have a mixture of #2 being *R* or *S* - but it has #1's chirality the *same* (s). This means not all chiral centers were flipped, creating diastereomer mixtures.

> He says if the reactant has no chiral carbon and product formed is chiral then it would be a racemic mixture. But why?

So that occurs whenever we transition that sp<sup>2</sup> carbon to sp<sup>3</sup>, turning the carbonyl into an alcohol (reduction), but that "*rule*" he gave says if there's no chiral carbon — we do actually have chiral carbons before the reaction starts — so the auto answer of "*racemic mixture*" doesn't quite apply here.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, welcome to ChemSE on your first post. Allow me to expand on the Comment of Karsten Theis and provide you with an illustration. If a compound is racemic and bears a **single** stereocenter, then it is properly represented without stereochemistry as shown in structure **1**. The example you provide is a single enantiomer, (*S*)-4-methylhexan-3-one, **1-S**. [If you are unfamiliar with *R,S*-nomenclature (CIP-rules), [go here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules).]
Let's presume that our Grignard reagent is methyl magnesium bromide. Without addressing [Felkin-Ahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_induction) issues, addition of the Grignard reagent to the carbonyl group of **1-S** from the front (next to the methyl group) will afford stereoisomer **3** while addition from the rear of the carbonyl group produces stereoisomer **4**. Both of these diastereomers are normally produced and invariably in unequal amounts. Why, you might ask. Felkin-Anh considerations notwithstanding, the reagent "sees" a methyl group from the frontside approach and a smaller hydrogen from the rear. There is difference in the energy of the two transition states. For the sake of argument, let's say that the ratio **2**/**3** is 3/1. Had you started with enantiomer **1-R**, the ratio of the diastereomers **4**/**5** [red box] would also be 3/1; they are the enantiomers of **2**/**3**, respectively. Enantiomers **2**-**5** are optically active.
Conducting the reaction on the racemate **1** will still give the same ratio 3/1 but the products will be racemic and not optically active.

[image]